# Python reduce function on objects

Tags: python, reduce

I am trying to write a function that takes in a list of employee object and returns the object that corresponds to the employee with the youngest age. I am not sure why it is breaking. I know there are many ways to do this but I am particularly interested in solving it through the reduce tool

```
from functools import reduce as r
class Employee:
    bonus = 0
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,age,salary):
        self.fullname = firstname + " "+ lastnamestname
        self.email = "{}{}@outlook.com".format(firstname,lastname)
        self.age = age
        self.compensation = salary + self.bonus

e1 = Employee("Adam","George",33,100)
e2 = Employee("Samuel","Steans",35,133)
e3 = Employee("Laura","Nobel",25,200)
e4 = Employee("David","Chan",21,100)
e5 = Employee("Ben","Smith",80,90)
e6 = Employee("Santa","Ergory",19,120)
e7 = Employee("Tim","Smith",18,150)
e8 = Employee("Paul","Goodfellow",50,180)

employees = [e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8]

def getyoungest(emps):
    return r(lambda x,y:x.fullname if x.age < y.age else y.fullname,emps )

youngest = getyoungest(employees)
print(youngest)
```

Comment: You should always use a list comprehension instead of `reduce`, see https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @Boris that isn't what you link is stating. Reduce, in general, cannot be replaced with a list comprehension, list comprehensions replace `filter`/`map` operations, not `reduce`. What Guido mentions in that link is that he personally prefers to just see reduce replaced by a loop with the accumulation explicitly

Answer (score 4):

For that you can use standard `min` function using the `key` parameter:

```
youngest = min(employees, key=lambda x:x.age)
```

Comment: Alternatively, [`import operator`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) and then `min(employees, key=operator.attrgetter('age'))`

Comment: @Boris: I know but I personally find that harder to read than `lambda x:x.age`

Comment: my comment was directed at the person asking. It might give them more flexibility, depending on what else they're trying to do. Also, I'm pretty sure `operator` is much faster.

Comment: @Boris: I beg to differ. May be your definition of "flexible" is different from mine but IMO `attrgetter` is way LESS flexible than a lambda where I can say for example `key=lambda x:x.age + x.seniority*4`. About speed let's just say that probably if you use Python (a good choice for many use cases) then speed for sure is not your main concern...

Answer (score 3):

You need to return an object in the lambda, not a name. Right now, on the second comparison it will effectively try to access `.age` of the previously returned fullname, which will definitely break.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to change `getyoungest` to:

```
def getyoungest(emps):
    return r(lambda x,y:x if x.age < y.age else y, emps)
```

I.e. return the youngest Employee, not the name of the youngest Employee.

Then add

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.fullname


#> ./reduce_objects.py 
Tim Smith
```